# Making Script Editor open and save a file via terminal(bash)

Tags: bash, macos, applescript

I want to make Script Editor open a .scpt file and then make a copy and save it as an application. And I want to automate all this as in I dont want to click on duplicate and save and then type everything.
Basically what I want to do

1. Open a xyz.scpt in Script Editor
2. Make a duplicate of it
3. Save the file as xyz.app (Should be saved as an application)

I think I should use applescript for this but if there is better way please tell me.
Currently the first 2 steps seem simple enough

```
open xyz.scpt 
osascript -e 'tell application "Script Editor" to activate' #Maybe redundant
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" keystroke "," using {command down,shift down}'
osascript -e 'keystroke "s" using {command down}'
```

After this I have no clue how to proceed. How do I make it change the name from "xyz copy" to "xyz" and save it as an application.

Note that any solution is ok. The solution need not be an AppleScript solution, it can be any type of solution.

Comment: What is meant by "duplicate it"? Is it just a simple copy, like `cp` does? Or does the script editor modifies any internal paths etc?

Comment: @anishsane Just a simple copy like cp

Comment: So, why go to all the trouble of opening in editor and save it? Why not just `cp`?

Comment: I need to save it as an application instead of the current format that is script or .scpt

Comment: So, it is not just cp :-) Anyway... you might want to look at the possibility of command line way to copy the script as an application. The UI mechanism is (1) slow and (2) difficult to run over ssh -X.

Comment: I would love a command line solution, but I really cant think of one that can change a file extension. And also the step 2 I mentioned could have been a simple cp instead of going around and messing with gui components.

Comment: [`osacompile -o MyScript.app MyScript.scpt`](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/how-do-i-make-an-applescript-file-into-a-mac-app) ?

Comment: Wow that worked like a charm, perfectly fits with what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot @anishsane

Comment: Added as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/8300):

There is a command-line mechanism for that:

```
osacompile -o MyScript.app MyScript.scpt
```

Marking the question as duplicate across sites is not possible. So posting as a separate answer here. Upvoters, please upvote the original answer at the line given. :-)

Answer (score 0):

in Script Editor, after opening your xyz.scpt, use the function "save as" with type application and your new file path. Here is the documentation (in Script Editor library window) :

**save** v : Save an object.
save specifier : the object for the command

[**as** text] : The file type in which to save the data. Use one of the following strings: "script", "script bundle", "application", "text".

[**in** alias] : The file in which to save the object.

[**run only boolean**] : Should the script be saved as Run-Only? If it is, you will not be able to edit the contents of the script again. The default is not to save as run only. (Applies to all script types except for "text").

[**startup screen boolean**] : Show the startup screen? The default is not to show the startup screen. (Only applies to scripts saved as "application").

[**stay open boolean**] : Should the application remain open after it is launched? The default is not to stay open. (Only applies to scripts saved as "application").

Try to avoid, as much as possible the GUI scripting (keystroke,...). Always look first if the application as scripting command. it's quicker and more safe.

Comment: Thanks for your help again @pbell. So to confirm in my terminal I should type `osascript -e 'save as application in "xyz"'`

Comment: When I try the above script it gives me the following error `execution error: «script» doesn’t understand the “save” message. (-1708)`

Comment: The exact syntax for the save in Applescript is : save front document as "application" in file "Users:myUser:myFolder:Test.app". you have to include that in your osascript command.  However, when I made the test, I found that sometime Script Editor need before the "compile" instruction to make sure the script is re-compiled before saving it as application.